# User does not have permission to access gs://xxxx.appspot.com/(null)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Getting "User does not have permission to access gs://xxxx.appspot.com/(null)"

After upgrading Firebase ( Firebase 5.1.0 (was 4.11.0), FirebaseStorage 3.0.0 (was 2.1.3)) and then making the code:

This was working code before upgrade:

```
imageUploadTask.observe(.success) { snapshot in

        let downloadURL = snapshot.metadata!.downloadURL()!.description
        addPostData(userId: userId, downloadURL: downloadURL)


    }
```

Code after upgrade since downloadURL is now deprecated for StorageMetaData:

```
imageUploadTask.observe(.success) { snapshot in

       storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in

        guard let downloadURL = url else { return }
        addPostData(userId: userId, downloadURL: downloadURL.description)

        }
```

printing the error in the completion block returns:
   "User does not have permission to access gs://xxxx.appspot.com/(null)"

What I have tried: (1) checked that the user is authenticated (Auth.auth().currentUser is not nil); (2) getting storageRef from snapshot.metadata.storageReference did not resolve this issue.

I want to continue to only allow authenticated users to upload images and will prefer not to change the Firebase storage rules.

Any ideas?

Comment: where are you assigning `storageRef` be cause that error implies that your ref is `gs://xxxx.appspot.com/(null)`

Comment: This post might help you. I think you have the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563347/firebase-storage-downloadurl-completion-handler-always-returns-error/50572011#50572011

Comment: @JenPerson Thanks for the pointer I spotted my mistake i was doing this `let storeageRef = Storage.storage().reference()` and have now changed it to `let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(imagestorePath)` and now it works

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and the solution (after rechecking the code samples in the [guide doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_files)) was to use the **Child** object representing the image file to call `downloadURL` method. look at the code below:

```
    // Upload the image
    let imagesFolder = Storage.storage().reference().child("images")      
    let imageFileName = NSUUID().uuidString + ".jpg"
    let imageFileObject = imagesFolder.child(imageFileName)

    imageUploadTask.observe(.success) { snapshot in
        imageFileObject.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            guard let downloadURL = url else { return }
            print("Url: \(downloadURL)")

            addPostData(userId: userId, downloadURL: downloadURL.description)
        })
    }
```